# JavaScript/Jquery Countdown timer integrated with PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, timer

I am a little bit stuck on this one and haven't really found anything that suits what I am trying to do so far. Basically what I want to do is allow users to input a time in seconds in a HTML form, this input will be sent when a button is pressed then this will start a countdown timer in terms of seconds counting down from the time that they inputted. This time will need to be echoed in PHP so the users can see the live status of their countdown and when the timer reaches 0, a message needs to be sent (could be a JS alert) saying "Countdown timer finished".

Comment: You just want a countdown? You shouldn't need php for that part..

Comment: Please post the code you've tried.

Comment: <script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
   
   var currentDate, targetDate, timeDif;
   
   currentDate= new Date().getTime();
   targetDate= currentDate + <?php $_POST['time'];?>;
   
   init();
   
   function init()
   {
    var Days, Hours, Minutes, Seconds
    
    timeDif = targetDate - currentDate
    
    function updateTime()
    {
    }
    
    function tick()
    {
     clearTimeout(timer);
     alert("Timer Ticking")
    }
    
    function displayTime()
    {
    }
    
    var timer = setTimeout(tick, 1*1000)
   }
   
   });
  </script>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Untested, but you should be able to do something like this...

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $time = $_POST['time'];
    ?>
    <div id="countdown"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var iTime = <?php echo $time; ?>;
        function countdown()
        {                
            var i = setInterval(function(){
                document.getElementById("countdown").innerHTML = iTime;
                if(iTime==0){
                    alert('Countdown timer finished!');
                    clearInterval(i);
                } else {
                    iTime--;
                }                   
            },1000);                        
        }           
        countdown();
    </script>
    <?php
} else {
    ?>
    <form name="test" method="post">
        Enter time: <input type="text" name="time" />
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
    </form>        
    <?php
}
 ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

ok ! so you are here confusing between background data and clientside data , this kind of interactive actions is only performed via JS in the client side, the php handle the background which means php do stuff before the page get shown to the user. 
so bottom line is , do it with javascript only

Comment: It is imperative that the user is able to see how many seconds is left, as that is the whole point.

Comment: in jquery put an id to a div : 
<div id="minutes"> 0 </div> 
and keep changing the content with : 
$('#minutes').html(numofminutes) ;